# Cython define fixed length array of pointers

Tags: python, cython

I am fairly new to Cython and haven't done any C in a long time, so this may be fairly obvious, but I don't know how to go about doing it. Consider the simple example of a binary tree:

```
ctypedef struct binary_node_t:
    double value
    binary_node_t[2] * children
```

Sure, I could just have `binary_node_t * left` and `binary_node_t * right`, but for my problem, I have more children, and it would be tedious, so I'd really like to have a fixed size array of pointers.

So when I'd want to initialize the node and its children, I'd like to do something like this:

```
cdef binary_node_t * root = <binary_node_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(binary_node_t))
root.children = <binary_node_t[2] *>PyMem_Malloc(2 * sizeof(binary_node_t))
```

The issue I'm facing is that `binary_node_t[2] *` doesn't seem to be valid and gives the following error during compilation

```
error: array type has incomplete element type ‘..._binary_node_t {aka struct ..._binary_node_t}’
   ..._binary_node_t (*children)[2];
                       ^~~~~~~~
```

What is the proper way to do what I'm trying to do, namely define a fixed length array of pointers to structs and allocating them when needed.

---

**EDIT 1**

I've also tried the standard C initialization, like so:

```
ctypedef struct binary_node_t:
    double value
    binary_node_t * children[2]

....
cdef binary_node_t * root = <binary_node_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(binary_node_t))
root.children = <binary_node_t * [2]>PyMem_Malloc(2 * sizeof(binary_node_t))
```

but this results in the following error

```
error: cast specifies array type
   memcpy(&(__pyx_v_root->children[0]), ((..._binary_node_t *[2])PyMem_Malloc((2 * (sizeof(..._binary_node_t))))), sizeof(__pyx_v_root->children[0]) * (2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn’t make much sense.

You don‘t have to allocate memory for `children` explicitly- it is already done by allocating memory for `root`. The size of the struct is 24 bytes: 8 bytes for value and 16 bytes for 2 children-pointers. Obviously, these two pointer-values are rubbish - you have to set them to 0 or to allocate the memory for them, if needed:

```
root.children[0]=<binary_node_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(binary_node_t));
root.children[1]=<binary_node_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(binary_node_t));
```

Maybe using `right` and `left` is easier to understand, as there is one indirection less.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is basically what I came to after reading the other answer, but thank you for writing it down explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried normal C declaration syntax?

```
binary_node_t *children[2]
```

You also don't need to malloc memory for `root.children` separately from `root`; the `children` array is part of the node, not a separate chunk of memory. (Or maybe you were trying to allocate the actual children there, not just space for the pointers. Whatever you were trying to do, that's not how you do it.)

Comment: I've also tried that, but ran across a different error. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Pavlin: You have another bug; you're trying to initialize an array by malloc'ing memory and assigning the resulting pointer to the array. You should take some time to refresh your memory of C before continuing with this project; working with Cython is going to require familiarity with both Python and C.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree, my C is very rusty. However, I think I see what you're saying. I should malloc every cell separately? I thought I could somehow get around that and do it all in one go.